# Meteor-angular: Add logic to retrieved collection before returning $scope.variable

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I have a `branches` collection, in which every document store `lat` and `lng` values. I need to find all the `branches` that are within a fixed circular range from a specific point (which gets read from the url after a post form). To perform such calculation I'm using [geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib)

As I'm new to Meteor, I'm having issue in understanding where to put such logic. As far as I understood I should use `Meteor.methods`, however the `find()` within my method does not retreive any results.

Here is my code:

```
// client/search/controllers/searchRestaurants.ng.js
angular.module("MyApp").controller("SearchRestaurantsCtrl",
    function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){

        $meteor.subscribe('branches');

        $scope.branches = $meteor.call('findNearestBranch', $stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lng);
    }
);


// model/branches.js
Meteor.methods({
    findNearestBranch: function(lat, lng) {

        var branches = {};

        // Branches.find().count(); returns 0; so the following does not get fired

        Branches.find().forEach(function(branch) {

            distance = geolib.getDistance(
                { latitude: lat, longitude: lng },
                { latitude: branch.lat, longitude: branch.lng }
            );

            if ( distance < 5000 ) {
                branches.push(branch);
            }
        });

        return branches;
    }
});


// client/search/views/search-restaurants.ng.html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="branch in branches">
        {{branch.name}}
    </li>
</ul>

// client/routes.ng.js
angular.module("MyApp").config(
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider
            .state('searchRestaurants', {
                url: '/search/:lat/:lng',
                templateUrl: 'client/search/views/search-restaurants.ng.html',
                controller: 'SearchRestaurantsCtrl'
            });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think methods are generally used for operations that create, modify or delete data, since those are the operations that you really need to protect. For finding and getting data, you typically just use methods on the collection object (like .find(...)) and use a publication to limit what documents are available in said collection (on the client).

That said, I would let the publication limit my results to only those that are applicable, which in you case would be those within a certain distance of the specified lat and lng coordinates. Additionally, I would use mongo's [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator instead of geolib.

Here is a pseudo-coded example of what I would do:

```
// in controller: assuming collection is called Branches
$meteor.subscribe('branches', {lat:$stateParams.lat, lng: $stateParams.lng});
$scope.branches = $meteor.collection(function() { return Branches.find(...); });

// in publication: assuming collection is called Branches and docs in the collection have a property called location.
Meteor.publish("branches", function (opts) {
   var lat = opts.lat, lng = opts.lng;

   return Branches.find({
      location: {
        $near: {
          $geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [lng, lat]
          },
          $maxDistance: 5000
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, thank you GPicazo. I didn't know about mongodb $near.

I ended up doing just this:

```
// Controller
angular.module("MyApp").controller("SearchRestaurantsCtrl",
    function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){

        $meteor.subscribe('branches');

        $scope.branches = $meteor.collection(function() {
            return Branches.find({
                loc: {
                    $near: {
                        $geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [ $stateParams.lng, $stateParams.lat]
                        },
                        $maxDistance: 5000
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
);


// View
<div ng-repeat="branch in branches">
    {{branch.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is fine, just keep in mind that by filtering you collection on client as opposed to the server (in the publication), you are sending more data than what is needed to the client. Either way, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Weirdly, if I try to implement your solution it errors: `$near requires a point, given { type: "Point", coordinates: [ "-121.88355687", "37.44609999" ] }`

Comment: If I tried the query directly on the db it was returning an error due to the lack of a index, so I've created it with `db.branches.ensureIndex({coordinates:"2dsphere"});` and now it works if querying directly mongo; however using meteor from server-side still does return the same error

Comment: Are the coordinate values quoted (strings)? I believe they may need to be floats.

Comment: Yep, that was it: `coordinates: [ Number(opts.lng), Number(opts.lat)]` thank you!

Comment: No problem. If you ended up implementing the solution I suggested in my original answer, please mark it as accepted.